# Angular material table is so slow even I have few rows

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I having an issue on angular material table is loading data so slow even I have few rows to show, My network in console shows that data is present but doesn't get rendered in table, sometimes it takes up to 6,7 mins to display data. I've been searching for solutions I found that who experienced this problem said to do pagination but this is for huge data but this is just few rows and I faced this.

This is network screenshot:

[image]

this is my table ui:

[image]

this is my table:

```html
<table class="w-full bg-transparent" mat-table matSort [dataSource]="tasks" [trackBy]="trackByFn"
  #recentTransactionsTable>
  <!-- Transaction ID -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
    <th mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef> Identifier </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let task">
      <span class="pr-6 font-medium text-sm text-secondary whitespace-nowrap">
        {{task.taskId}}
      </span>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let task">
      <span class="pr-6 whitespace-nowrap">
        {{task.name}}
      </span>
    </td>
  </ng-container>


  <!-- Date -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="createTime">
    <th mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef> Create Time </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let task">
      <span class="pr-6 whitespace-nowrap">
        {{task.createTime | date:'MM/dd/y'}}
      </span>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="assignee">
    <th mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef> Assignee </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let task">
      <span class="pr-6 whitespace-nowrap">
        {{task.assignee}}
      </span>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Amount -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
    <th mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>
      Description
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let task">
      <span class="pr-6 whitespace-nowrap">
        {{task.description}}
      </span>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Status -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
    <th mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>
      Action
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let task">
      <button mat-mini-fab color="primary" style="transform: scale(0.8)" [routerLink]="[task.taskId]">
        <span class="inline-flex items-center">
          <mat-icon svgIcon="feather:share-2"></mat-icon>
        </span>
      </button>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="recentOrdersTableFooter">
    <td class="py-6 px-0 border-0" mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef colspan="6">
      <button mat-stroked-button>See all transactions</button>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="recentTransactionsTableColumns"></tr>
  <tr class="order-row h-16" mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: recentTransactionsTableColumns;"></tr>
  <tr class="h-16 border-0" mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="['recentOrdersTableFooter']"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: *takes up to 6,7 mins to display data.* did really wait that long to see the effect ??;)

Comment: Maybe you are in PUSH detection strategy and you have forgot to call detectChanges() ?? Include component code.

Comment: Try remove the `[trackBy]="trackByFn"` and check where you equal your variable "tasks" to the data. See also if you has in console any error or you're inside a infinite loop

Comment: @Antoniossss Yes I'm using OnPush strategy, and `markForcheck()`, but still the same.

Comment: @Eliseo tried that removed it and same thing

Comment: do detectChanges instead of markForCheck